# Adding individual id tags to table cells with Rails each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails each loop, I have a certain `<td>` that I want to add an id to, so that when I click the button a javascript method on the page that uses that id will trigger before the linked method will call. It works fine on the first go, but since each entry will have the same id at that cell, all the rest of the buttons dont work.

Comment: if you are repeating ID's use class instead. If button is in that row is easy to find with a DOM traverse. You need to post some code for anyone to help beyond that

Comment: It sounds like you need to establish a variable to act as an iterator - you know, starting at 1 and then increasing each time automatically. Is that what you're looking to do? So - the first <td> would have an id of 1, next <td> id of 2, etc etc...If so, that's a pretty quick and easy thing to implement in ruby/rails.

Comment: @JonathanBowman if i do that, how can I set the javascript code to recognize it, right now Im using something like:('#id').on('click', function(e) {

Comment: If the JS isn't super duper complicated then you can just put it between <script> tags and have them generated automatically by rails in the view along with the <td> elements, then you can use the same ruby variable in both the HTML id and the id the javascript is using to target it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an id use a class instead. 
For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example table site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="example">I'm a table cell</td>
                <td>I'm a table cell that doesn't have anything happen when you click</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="example">Click Me</td>
                <td>Another boring cell</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            $(".example").click(function (e) {
                console.log('table cell clicked');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```